# TWebBrowser - Trying to fix the "Invalid floating point operation" error

Tags: delphi, ole, message, twebbrowser

The `TWebBrowser` component has an error as described here [[IE9] 'Floating point division by zero' occurs with WebBrowser](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=102469). The solution is to call a procedure that will disable all division by zero exceptions. I am trying to fix this problem without having to call this procedure.

So far, the best idea I had was to disable `TWebBrowser` scroll bars and try to simulate the same functionality using a `TScrollBar`. So far, it is working but that is the question:

How can I synchronize the navigation in the `TWebBrowser` with `TScrollBar`? I need to intercept scroll messages of `TWebBrowser` and send them to `TScrollBar` in order to keep the bar synchronized with the document that is being show. Does anyone knows how to do that?

To be more clear: I need an way of telling `TScrollBar` what is its position relative to the position of the cursor in the `TWebBrowser`.

I am using Delphi 2010.

Comment: You should solve this by masking FP exceptions. I can't imagine why you want to make life so painful for yourself.

Comment: The linked QC entry comments  already tells you the solution: `Set8087CW($133F);` before call, and then restore it afterwards, if you REALLY want floating point exceptions to be back again after the web browser goes away. There is no alternative.

Comment: If your app has more than 1 Delphi thread then calling Set8087CW is not an option due to its thread unsafety and the fact that it changes Default8087CW which can also leak into other threads.

Comment: This is not the answer to your question, but a potential workaround. IE 8 and up has BROWSER EMULATION feature (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation) in the registry applicable to IE browser and webbrowser control. With this setting, you can run IE to behave like IE10, IE9, IE8, or IE7. Try with different setting, and test if your problem goes away. Note: if your IE is 64 bit, the key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  I'm working in C++ Builder 5 at the moment... they STILL haven't fixed the thread safety issues in newer versions?!?  (The number of design flaws I see in this old version that seem uncorrected in newer versions based on looking at the online documentation is appalling)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the suggestion I have is to make appropriate calls as soon as your image is entered and set the FPUCW to the same as Visual C++ (53-bit precision, no exceptions): top of WinMain for EXEs, process attach (only!) for DLL's DllMain.  Then, never change it again.  Deviating from Microsoft's defaults only results in pain & suffering in my experience.

Comment: @James That's no good. Unmasking exceptions is better. It's possible with a bit of skill and understanding to fix the bugs at runtime with code hooks. My QC report has details: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=107411

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Sounds like the designers at Embarcadero still pretend there is only one thread in a program, just like they did over 10 years ago.  Your document is also Delphi-centric: remember that C++ Builder has _control87 and that modifies a _default87 variable with similar problems as Default8087CW.  Worse, _default87 is not Default8087CW so they step on each other if you forget to update both.  _default87 used for C++ exceptions and Default8087CW used for VCL things like TThread.

Comment: Regarding unmasking exceptions being better than my approach: can you outline a realistic plan besides "fix everything"?  I have had problems with IE web browser control throwing FPU exceptions.  Also OpenGL throws exceptions, VCL documentation itself suggests disabling exceptions in this case.  Others have noted on here that some drivers etc. set FPUCW to the typical Visual C++ defaults too.  Am I to fix every Visual C++ / Microsoft-written DLL, and 3rd-party DLLs that I load in my program which assumes no FPU exceptions / 53-bit precision?

Comment: @JamesJohnston Yeah, I know nothing about C++ and so Delphi centric, guilt as charged. When you call into those other libraries, you have to give them the FPUCW that they want. In my case it is the Python engine using the yaml unit that makes my app gag. Give that code the standard MS FPUCW and it's all good.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Easier said than done I think.  Sounds ideal, but we make very extensive use of one open source 3D C++ library throughout our project.  I can't imagine how many hundreds (thousands?) of set FPUCW / restore FPUCW operations would have to be scattered throughout the code - what a dirty unmaintainable mess.  The far simpler solution seems to be to just set the FPUCW to same as Visual C++ in WinMain, then work around the fewer issues that creates.

Comment: Well, it depends. In my situation, all calls to the Python DLL have to claim the Python GIL. And so I wrap that in a function that also saves away FP control state and sets to MS standard. Then reverses on the way out. Similarly in my DLL code all entry points do similar with control word. It takes discipline but in my view it's worthwhile. It's much harder to do with asynchronous code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe it is worthwhile to try.  The scrolling in IE is going to happen with or without its scroll bars being visible ... using your TScrollbar is apparently going to scroll the browser which in turn is assumedly going to generate the same exact error.  I don't know the internals of IE to know where exactly this floating point error surfaces...

Are you after all scroll bars, or just the outer one?  What about internal content that is scrolled, such as an embedded frame?  Do the other internal scroll bars on a document  generate the same error?  If they do, then you'll be chasing your tail for quite a while trying to out-do IE on all it's scrollable content.

The fix is provided, and tested.  Sorry, but I'd use the suggested fix.

Comment: Well .. the error does not occur without the scrollbars being visible. The error only occurs when I click on the scrollbar, so i am assuming this is possible and worthwhile to try.

Comment: Are you going to remove the scrollbars on combo boxes, edit boxes, embedded frames too?